# filtering publisher traffic (outscale publisher) fails

Tags: 2011, publishing, mmc

We're trying to set up publisher (rendering/deploying) filtering in the Tridion MMC.

When we set up multiple publication targets in the filtering, we get following error upon restart of the publisher service:

`Sequence contains more than one matching element`

Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing 
Errorcode: 0 
User: ****

StackTrace Information Details: 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Queuing.QueuingEngine.AddMissingFilters(IList`1 listQueueFilterData) 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Queuing.QueuingEngine.OpenQueue(Int32 queueId, Int32 configurationId) 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Queuing.QueuingEngine.CreateQueueConsumer(Int32 queueId, Int32 configurationId) 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.QueueConsumerHandler.DoWork()`

[image: setup in MMC]

Someone had a similar issue and knows how to fix it? It's a 2011 SP1 server, HR + other hotfixes installed.

Comment: Not one I've seen before.  The 'AddMissingFilters' and 'Sequence contains more than one matching element' error messages would seem to suggest that there is a problem getting the default values for the three filters that you have (correctly) not entered.  Not a solution, but adding values to these (e.g. Priorities='2', Publications='tcm:0-99-1' & Hostnames='http://yourCmsServer') and seeing what happens could give you more information to go to Tridion Support with (or add here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a hotfix for the given problem (77810), but it's supposed to be included in 2011 SP1 HR1. It's best to contact customer support

Comment: this was indeed (initially) included by the HR1, but somehow the GAC dll of tridion.contentmanager.queuing got overridden when installing some event system stuff in the GAC. Thx for the help!